# Bad kerning of number characters in matplotlib labels

Tags: python, fonts, matplotlib

I recently adjusted my matplotlibrc file to start using Arial as a the default sans-serif font. After doing this, I noticed some issues with numbers (specifically, y-axis tick labels) not lining up properly. See this example:
[image]
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1391730/Capture.PNG

After reverting to the default font I saw that the issue was still there, it's just less pronounced (Arial's "1" seems to be very narrow, so without some sort of spacing adjustment you get results like the one above). I'm hoping there's some other RC param I can adjust to fix this, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: There has been a bunch of work done on this recently.  What version are you using?  I think the fixes went into 1.3.0.

Comment: I just upgraded to 1.4.x, but the issue persists.

Comment: Can you post code to generate than png?

Comment: The other option is to set `rcParams['text.usetex'] = True to have LaTeX do the rendering for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Experimenting with tex options led me to setting "pdf.use14corefonts: True", which solved the problem (although I'm not sure why...)

Comment: Can you please post an answer with your solution?

Answer (score 1):

The kerning seems fine to me, the problem is alignment. The developer chose to align to the graph. This is most easily solved by not using a proportional font but a font with a fixed widtdh (monospaced font). Try something like Arial Monospaced Regular and Deja Vu Sans Mono (or any other font you like).